# My player doesn't respect the box collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, unityscript

I am programming a player (a red cube)... In my scenario there are a lot of walls... Unfortunately my player walks through wall... How can I fix it?

So here are my scripts (js) :

```
  #pragma strict

    function Start () {

    }

 function Update () {


   if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);


 }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);


   }
       if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
           transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);


   }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
       transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime);



    }


   }
```

My player has a box collider and my walls have one too... (and he IS NOT trigger)...

Comment: It is entirely possible that in deltaTime your player crosses from one side of the wall to another and your collision tests only check for a player ending up 'inside' a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a `Rigidbody` to your player `gameobject`

For collisions to work in Unity, one of the colliding objects need to have a `Rigidbody` attached to it. The `Rigidbody` is usually attached to the `gameobject` which is non-static. In your case your player `gameobject` is non static and requires a `Rigidbody` attached to it in order to process collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively the difference between `Collider`s and `RigidBody` could be thought as follows.

Physics calculations are done in another world, in other words, physics engines have their own world and all calculations/simulations are done there. `Collider`s actually provide information for the physics simulator (as an information input), and `RigidBody`s, in other side, act as output pipe.

```
+-----------+
|   +---+   |  input
|   | A |---|---------->   
|   +---+   |
|           |             Physics Calculation World
|   +---+   |  output
|   | B |<--|-----------
|   +---+   |
+-----------+
```

In this picture, `A` is only a collider and `B` have a rigid body.

- `input`: Sends physics-related information to physics calculation world. (acts passively)
- `output`: Gives information from physics world and **apply** them to the game object. (acts actively)

Therefore, we could sum up as follows:

- `Collider`: Passive / Information provider for physics simulation.
- `RigidBoy`: Active / Applies physics calculated results to game object.